# i just killed windows 10 and put ubuntu on my laptop. problem is my touchpad will not work

Tags: touchpad

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                                Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

this is what im getting when i try to make my touchpad work any help would be nice and its 14.04 ubuntu. thank you

Comment: This line: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902) tells you that one package depends on another package to be higher in the version than the locally installed one.This usually hints to outdated software. It's generally recommended to update the software first before installing new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to update your software:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core xorg-input-abi-20 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```